# Granting a Thread low priority in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

If I want  grant a Thread a low priority whats the correct call?

```
Thread t= new Thread(r);
t.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
```

or

```
Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_LOWEST);
```

Or maybe should I combine both? If yes is the order of this calls important? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`t.setPriority(int)` will set the priority on `Thread t`. This can not be used to set a Thread's priority higher than the receiver's `ThreadGroup`.

`Process.setThreadPriority(int, int)` takes an additional argument, so that you can set the priority on any Thread (granted a `SecurityException` is not thrown).

Also notice the integer value of `Thread.MIN_PRIORITY` (1) and `Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_LOWEST` (19).